# Docker not starting after setting iptables to false

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I run server with ubuntu 17.04. I decided to try docker for my new project. I realized that docker does not play nicely with firewalls because it alters iptables on its own. So I browsed docker docs and found out that you can prevent that from happening by creating json file with flag like this:

/etc/docker/daemon.json

```
{
          "iptables": false
}
```

However after trying to restart the docker daemon I ran into an error:

```
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

More details:

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2017-09-26 16:53:35 UTC; 1min 4s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 2450 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 2450 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
      CPU: 26ms

Sep 26 16:53:35 humblefund systemd[1]: docker.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1
Sep 26 16:53:35 humblefund systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Sep 26 16:53:35 humblefund systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 26 16:53:35 humblefund systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 26 16:53:35 humblefund systemd[1]: docker.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling res
Sep 26 16:53:35 humblefund systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
Sep 26 16:53:35 humblefund systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Sep 26 16:53:35 humblefund systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Sep 26 16:53:35 humblefund systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 26 16:53:35 humblefund systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

The other output:

```
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit docker.socket has begun starting up.
Sep 26 16:53:35 humblefund systemd[1]: Listening on Docker Socket for the API.
-- Subject: Unit docker.socket has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit docker.socket has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Sep 26 16:53:35 humblefund systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Sep 26 16:53:35 humblefund systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit docker.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Sep 26 16:53:35 humblefund systemd[1]: docker.socket: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 26 16:53:35 humblefund systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 26 16:53:35 humblefund systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

**EDIT:**

---

After running dockerd -D command output looks like this:

```
unable to configure the Docker daemon with file /etc/docker/daemon.json: invalid character 'Ã' looking for beginning of object key string
```

Comment: Run `docker daemon -D` and see what error do you get?

Comment: @TarunLalwani the command returns this `invalid character 'Ã' looking for beginning of object key string`

Comment: Please change the content to `{"iptables": false}`. No spaces, no newlines. and try again

Comment: @TarunLalwani it seems to be stuck on line `INFO[0001] API listen on /var/run/docker.sock`

Comment: Try `sudo docker ps` in another terminal. The command I gave you will not end or go to background. If it is stuck there then that means it is working. Once `docker ps` works you can close this and try again with the service command `service docker start`